# What actually happened between Spock and Saavik?

Tags: star-trek, spock, the-search-for-spock

In Star Trek III, Saavik tells David that Spock is about to go through Pon Faar, and that he will need to mate to survive. Later on, she is shown performing some kind of ritual with her hands with Spock which seems to calm him down quite a bit, but then the scene ends.

At this point, did they have intimate relations? The film really wasn't clear on this, and I couldn't tell if we were supposed to infer that or not.

Comment: I've posted [a new meta question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3070/5184)

Comment: There's a scene later where the three of them stand defiantly in front of the Klingons with (seventeen-year-old) Spock looking especially self-satisfied. I can imagine Harve Bennet pointing to Saavik and saying "imagine you just hit that."

Comment: Also note the initiation gestures of it was inspired by how Sarek and Amanda held hands in Journey to Babel.

Answer (score 9):

**You are lead to infer that Spock and Saavik did indeed participate in the physical and mental aspects of the pon farr ritual. Spock experienced an accelerated version of pon farr due to the Genesis planet's influence in Star Trek III: The Search for Spock, as a young man. He was aided by fellow half-Vulcan, Saavik.**

- **Pon Farr:** Every seven years, Vulcan males and females become aroused. They undergo a blood fever, become violent, and finally die unless they mate with someone with whom they are empathically bonded or engage in the ritual battle known as kal-if-fee. (In the Prime Star Trek universe - see: [Memory Alpha -> Alternate reality](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Alternate_reality))

> Later that year, Saavik was transferred to the Grissom, where she further studied the Genesis Planet along with Kirk's son, David Marcus. There, they found the body of Captain Spock, who was believed lost. When Saavik and David found him, Spock's regenerated body was physiologically that of a child, but he aged rapidly. Saavik helped Spock through the agonies of the pon farr. After she and her companions were captured by Klingons, Saavik was almost murdered by a d'k tahg-wielding Klingon officer, though she was saved by David Marcus, who was instead violently killed by the Klingon. Saavik returned to Vulcan with the Enterprise crew, to reintegrate Spock's katra into his body, in 2285. (Star Trek III: The Search for Spock) --[Memory Alpha -> Saavik entry](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Saavik)

- For Spock to have survived, it is indeed fortunate that Saavik was available, as it is considered unusual for a Vulcan to survive pon farr without the support of other Vulcans at least before the reboot of the Trek Universe in the Abrams **[Star Trek (2009)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_%28film%29)** timeline.

Comment: I recall drafting a comedy sketch at the time centering on the idea that based on Spock's age, he probably went through pon-farr SEVERAL TIMES as he grew to adulthood, leaving poor Saavik in quite the untenable position.  
(Sighs, voice shaking) "Okay...calm...CALLLLMMM..."

Answer (score 3):

I refer you to this well-crafted and informative video:

Yes, intimate relations were inferred to commence as part of the ritual of which the hand-touching was the beginning.

Comment: The video is gone

Comment: Video works for me.

Comment: `Video unavailable` `This video contains content from CBS CID, who has blocked it in your country on copyright grounds`

Answer (score 2):

Although the film is quite coy and cuts away from the actual naughtiness, we're left under no illusions that they had (ahem) [physical relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4Myq.jpg), that being the only known way to cure a Vulcan's [*'pon farr'*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Pon_farr) urges.

> *Spock reached up and gently touched her cheek. His fingers followed the upward stroke of her eyebrow, then curved down to caress her temple, as Saavik met the gaze of his gold-flecked brown eyes.*
>
> [several hours later later]
>
> *Saavik smoothed Spock's tangled hair. The fever had broken, the compulsion had left him. He slept, and he would live. She wondered if she had done him a kindness by saving his life. He was still completely vulnerable to the convulsions of Genesis, which would continue to torture him.*
>
> <sub><sup>Star Trek: The Search for Spock - Official Novelisation</sup></sub>

and

> He is more in control now... intense. His eyes turn and lock on hers. Hands touching, they move together until their faces are brushing... and their fingers embrace.
>
> [later]
>
> CUT TO:
> INT. CAVE - GENESIS - CLOSE - THE YOUNG SPOCK:
> Morning light is streaming in. His eyes are closed, he breathes calmly. A hand, Saavik's, ENTERS SHOT, to sooth his brow and smooth his matted hair.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek 3 - Script](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/Trek/Star_Trek_III.htm)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

During an interview, the writer of Star Trek III, stated that Saavik was in fact pregnant with Spocks child. This is why she stayed behind on Vulcan when Kirk and his crew returned to face charges in Star Trek 4. Star Trek II, III and IV were written as a trilogy. Which is why each movie picked up where the other left off. Unfortunately they decided to leave it at that, and not develop the part of the story where Saavik is pregnant with Spock's child, or even disclose this fact to the audience.

There are bonus Featurette videos included with the latest 4k release of the 1-6 movie series. On the Star Trek IV movie, a featurette called the "Three Movie Saga", has all of this information covered by interviews. I believe Harve Bennett confirmed this information in one of the statements he made in that featurette. Harve Bennett did the Story, and the screenplay of the movie.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: During which interview? Who was speaking and where was it published?

Comment: https://screenrant.com/star-trek-spock-baby-deleted-canon-saavik-why/ This seems to back up your assertion that they thought of it originally but it mentions that they cut it out of the script entirely, rendering it merely a suggested plotline

Comment: It was certainly a well-known rumor at the time, but I can't think of any definitive evidence to its veracity.  I vaguely recall an interview with Robin Curtis in Starlog which might have mentioned it, but again I may be mentally manufacturing that.